# Publish to Groups Permission? - Facebook Graph Academy Lesson 4 - Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm on lesson 4 of Facebook's graph API Tutorial.

This is the message they want you to type verbatim.

`FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', {'message': ''});`

This is the error message I receive

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "YaddaYadDaYadDA"
  }
}`

I manage a company Facebook Page, and a personal project Facebook Page

What is the issue and how do I fix?

Already tried setting the Facebook Graph Academy app permissions to Public and tried deleting and reinstalling the app to my FB account.

Comment: so...do you want to post to a group, or a page?  there is a big difference. and did you authorize with the required permissions already? what access token are you using? user token? page token? /me/feed would post to a page only, there i s no  group token and posting to profiles is not possible anymore. so you do need a page token with the publish_pages permission.

Comment: Honestly, this is page 4 of the tutorial, so I have no idea what I want to do. If what you're saying is correct, it's an outdated tutorial?

The tutorial said, click this button (connecting the FB Tutorial App to my account) and click "run program".

The program was the line above.

Though FB installed the app, and I could see that in my FB account when I checked, the tutorial checkbox for that specific activity wouldn't light up.

The tutorial wanted me to post something to my personal profile using /me/feed. The OAuth error seems like it's trying to post on a page I manage instead.

Comment: To clarify, I think the tutorial is a sandbox environment, so I can't go to the app itself and manage or find auth tokens/codes. In addition, I'm not far enough along in the tutorial to where they've taught authentication via command line with no pre-existing codes.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/graph-academy/graph-api-basics/4/

Comment: yes, then it is outdated. posting to your personal profile with /me/feed is not possible anymore. the error is misleading.

Comment: So... is there a good place to get a tutorial on how to use the Fb graph API?

Comment: the official docs offer everything you need.

Comment: @luschn Except that their tutorial is broken? Can I still trust their docs?

Comment: @user2208569 Have you been able to find a solution or a workaround to this problem?

Comment: Anyway, I have raised a bug with Facebook for developers: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/315103335792477/?disable_redirect=0. I really hope it's a duplicate and the problem was acknowledged earlier between January and today.

Comment: Update: Based on [this answer](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/315103335792477/?comment_id=315133675789443) from Facebook support, they're not going to fix the Graph API course and are instead referring to documentatioon.